# Suggest tool for website structure prototyping

Tags: user-interface, prototyping

I am looking for some tool that would help me prototype basic website structure and logistics (or simply user interface).

It should be extremely efficient in the matter of time needed to do simple changes like changing position of objects on the page. It should provide features for creating multiple pages and linking them together.

I don't need visual aspect of the thing, just the basic structure, placement of objects and logistics.

I prefer offline, free or open source solution.

Comment: Are there no free offline solutions? Hmm...

Comment: Related (duplicate?) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112803/what-is-the-best-web-prototyping-tool

Comment: I developed a complete wordpress like php solution for wireframe and you can try it at https://www.wireframes.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Mockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com/), it's mainly used for user interface prototypes, but you can easily use it for flowcharts / structure diagrams etc.

Best of all it's free!

Comment: Nice tool, but but free version allows 1 user, 1 project, 10 pages: which is hardly enough for a proper project...

Comment: Yea, they have great "free" plan, just for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/), it's excellent and quite inexpensive. Or, Microsoft's [Sketchflow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_OverView.aspx) is great for building interactive prototypes.

Comment: Agreed. I've been using it in anger for a month or so, and it's great for fostering discussions with clients and is easy enough to change designs on the fly. Also has a great 'presentation' mode.

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order:

- [Sketchflow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow_Overview.aspx), part of [Expression Blend 3](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx)
- [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)
- [Mockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com/)
- [Axure](http://www.axure.com/)

Answer (score 1):

*"I prefer offline, free or open source solution."*

Then [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [iPlotz](http://iplotz.com/) recently which is an online wireframing tool and I've been impressed.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend Mockplus Cloud.

Mockplus is a desktop-based tool for prototyping mobile, web, and apps. You are able to create interactions with simple drag-and-drop. Besides，your teamwork will be time-efficient with the collaboration feature.

The admins are always online and can solve your problems in minutes if you have any. You can learn about design and get design inspirations and resources in this group.

What’s more, this group offers many benefits to its members only.

If you join the Mockplus and the admin will offer you 40% off coupons and free UI Kits & Fonts Package. Besides, you will get life-time free tech support on Mockplus even if you are not a paid user now.

If you are looking for a place to communicate with others about product and UX/UI design, and also get a great rapid prototyping tool with saving a big budget.